# jQuery slideshow with controlers opposite action

Tags: jquery, animation

I've a slideshow animation with a tiny bit of jquery code that I like. When I press next the animation run well. But when I try to do the opposite using prev I've one duplicate action before it goes revert.

any ideas how I could jump this ?

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

$("#after").click(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .appendTo('#slideshow')

    .fadeOut(1000)
    .prev()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end();

});
```

See here : https://codepen.io/1conu59/pen/bzJdzz

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the answer !

Here 's the logic behind this :

```
//Comments explanation

$("#btnAfter").click(function() {

   // I select the first div, the one at the top
  $('#slideshow > div:first')

    // I put it at the end of the stack
    .appendTo('#slideshow')    
});

// Here is the opposite logic
$("#btnPrev").click(function() {

  // Here I select the last div, the one at the bottom
  $('#slideshow > div:last')

    //I put it at the top of the stack which also move the dom selection with it
    .prependTo('#slideshow')        
});
```

Here is the result : https://codepen.io/1conu59/pen/gqJPjP

This create a really clear mind logic of DOM manipulation, similar to mixin a stack of cards.

This is few ressources which help me a lot on it :

https://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-adding-elements/

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_traversing.asp